# Using pandas, how to find the value counts by two columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas data frame with three columns, Protein_A, Protein_B, Interaction.
[see it here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jKDNP.png)

I want to find all the interactions as value counts by grouping Protein_A and Protein_B.  Additionally, the order does not matter when grouping Protein_A and Protein_B.

```
    Protein_A   Interaction      Protein_B
0   A1BG        ER               A2M
1   A1BG        MI               ABCC6
2   ABCC6       AS               A1BG
3   A1BG        MI               ADAM10
4   A1BG        MI               ADAM17
```

The result will look something like this:

```
{AB1G, A2M}     -> ER
{AB1G, ABCC6}   -> MI, AS
{A1BG, ADAM10}  -> MI
{A1BG, ADAM17}  -> MI
```

Comment: You say in the question that you want `value counts` but the result you show just shows the interaction column.  Can you clarify your intent by modifying the question or fixing the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that you want to **group** rows, but the expected result shows that
instead of **value counts** for each group you actually want a **list**
of interaction codes.

To create such a list (for each group) proceed as follows:

Start from defining a function, which calculates the grouping key
- a sorted list of protein codes (A and B), converted into a string:

```
def protSorted(key):
    row = df.loc[key]
    return ', '.join(sorted([row.Protein_A, row.Protein_B]))
```

Then group the source DataFrame by this function, take *Interaction*
column from each group and create a list of interaction codes:

```
df.groupby(protSorted).Interaction.apply(list)
```

For your sample data, the result is a *Series* like below:

```
A1BG, A2M           [ER]
A1BG, ABCC6     [MI, AS]
A1BG, ADAM10        [MI]
A1BG, ADAM17        [MI]
Name: Interaction, dtype: object
```

Or if you want for each group a **string** (without surrounding brackets),
run instead:

```
df.groupby(protSorted).Interaction.apply(', '.join)
```

This time the result is:

```
A1BG, A2M           ER
A1BG, ABCC6     MI, AS
A1BG, ADAM10        MI
A1BG, ADAM17        MI
Name: Interaction, dtype: object
```